# iPhone 5 retina 4 inch touch screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm adapting my app to iphone 5 and I've got a problem. I saw all documentation regarding this and it didn't work yet.

I put the Default-568h@2x.png and everything resized successfully.

The problem is in the touch stuff. I've got a toolbar on the bottom and when I touch it nothing happens :( in the retina 4" simulator. Works fine in retina 3.5

In retina 4", if I set the toolbar in the inspector above 439 px in the Y position works fine. Anything below this makes my toolbar not to work.

As I said, I tried many many things unsuccessfully.

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1, I've got a Main View (not having a Window option in the Attributes inspector).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window or the main view is not resizing correctly. Make sure you have set them up such that they autoresize in both directions. Try to set different background colors to your views to find the view that is not resizing correctly.

Comment: If you are using arc, just copy paste this where you create the `UIWindow` in appDelegate: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that all of your views are auto-resizing correctly to fill the screen. It sounds like the main container view you have isn't being resized and is drawing the toolbar outside of its frame. This will work from a visual point of view as `UIView - clipsToBounds` defaults to NO, but touches won't work outside the frame.